# Touch event handling with MaskToBounds NO

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I was trying to implement a container view controller design into my app. However I was told that I need to support iOS 4.3 devices, so the official view controller API introduced in iOS 5 is not an option at the moment.

In order to achieve a similar behaviour I used a hack. Resized the view for my RootViewController and the added a subview to it that it's outside the view's bounds. For example: RootView has bounds 0,0,320,480. Now I resized it to 0,0,320,430 and included a subview at 0,430,320,60. This works since I do all calculations using the ApplicationFrame giving me stable frames on which to work. But the problem I'm facing right now is that the subview which is out of the bounds of the view is not receiving touch events. The `maskToBounds = NO` property helps me with the display. But touches? Anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want the subview to receive touch events in such cases, you can do the following:

1- Create a new class that inherits from `UIView` and override `hitTest:withEvent:` to allow subviews to intercept touches:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
@end

@implementation CustomView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /// Check if the point is inside the subview
    CGPoint newPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
    if ([subview pointInside:newPoint withEvent:event]) {
        /// Let the subview decide the return value
        return [subview hitTest:newPoint withEvent:event];
    }

    /// Default route
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

2- Change the class of root view to our `CustomView` (from the right panel in Xcode > Identity Inspector > Custom Class).

And we're done!